# Bulma how to inherit an helper

Tags: css, bulma

Hello I was wondering for this simple piece of code :

```
<span class="is-italic">Hello <span class="is-normal???">World</span></span>
```

how can I make "World" not italic. Is there an helper allows me to inherit text transformation ? Or the only way is to use css ?

https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no Bulma helper built in to do this.

#### Option 1

Change your HTML to:

`<span class="is-italic">Hello</span> World`

#### Option 2

Make a custom CSS helper:

```
.is-normal {
  font-style: normal;
}
```